# ShareActionProvider with dynamic Extras changes

Tags: android, android-intent

I've **ShareActionProvider** in my application and I can share text which I defined in my **Intent Extras** in my **OnCreateOptionsMenu** method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
        myShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, siteUrl);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
        return true;
    }
```

I have a couple AsyncTask's which change my `public static siteUrl`
How to change the Extras part of the Intent, when AsyncTask is finished ?

I will be grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out , how to change shared extras dynamically using **BroadcastReceiver**.

I create filter flag:

```
public static SHAREDACTIONUPDATE = "SHAREDACTIONUPDATE";
```

and new **BroadcastReceiver()** Instance:

```
BroadcastReceiver onNotice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, actualTrackVideoUrl);
            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            if (myShareActionProvider != null) {
                myShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(myIntent);
            }
        }
    };
```

Then I **registerReceiver()** with IntentFilter in **onCreateOptionMenu()** method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onNotice,
                new IntentFilter(ActivityStation.UPDATEINTENTEXTRAS));
```

Finally I call that Broadcast in AsyncTasks **onPostExecute()** method:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ActivityStation.UPDATEINTENTEXTRAS));
```

And everything works fine.